# If Condition Issue in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Im trying to get this done and bit stuck please help me on it.

I want if D2 = "BAM" Then the Total  (H2) will also be shown in L2 and if D2="GAM" Then Total Must be Shown on M2 (not on L2 )

[image: My Sheet Preview]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: New Rows are Added up so I need the formula to be active till the 400th Row

Answer (score 1):

#### Formula:

L2: `=arrayformula(if(D2:D="BAM", H2:H, ""))`

M2: `=arrayformula(if(D2:D="GAM", H2:H, ""))`

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- `Arrayformula` will automatically populate columns L and M until the last row available.